# How to programmatically get a list of wireless SSIDs in range from NetworkManager

Tags: wireless, network-manager, application-development, pygi

I'm writing a small little app that I want to submit to the Ubuntu App Review board, and one thing I'd like to do is for it to show the names of the detected Wireless SSIDs in a combo box. It's a PyGI app.

Has anyone got any pointers on how I can get those SSIDs from the system, preferably through a Python API? From dbus? From NetworkManager?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this easily from NetworkManager's pygi bindings:

```
from gi.repository import NetworkManager, NMClient

nmc = NMClient.Client.new()
devs = nmc.get_devices()

for dev in devs:
    if dev.get_device_type() == NetworkManager.DeviceType.WIFI:
        for ap in dev.get_access_points():
            print ap.get_ssid()
```

Or from DBus directly, see
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/examples/python/show-bssids.py

If you're inclined to just quickly script this in shell; an easy way to ask NetworkManager for this is to use:

```
nmcli dev wifi list
```

Or use *iwlist scan*, or better: *iw dev wlan0 scan* (or *... scan dump*), after installing the [iw](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/iw) [image: Install iw] package.

Comment: I realise this is an old question, but is there a place where NetworkManager and NMClient are documented?

Comment: See [python-networkmanager on GitHub](https://github.com/seveas/python-networkmanager) which links to [the documentation](http://packages.python.org/python-networkmanager/) :-)

Answer (score 3):

One option is to run `iwlist scan` on the command line, but it has to be run as **root**

Comment: Ah, that's something I can use, but I'd prefer accessing them at an API level rather than through command line and subprocess calls, so I think I'll end up accepting Mathieu's answer. In any case, thanks for your answer!